# How to make https URL to http

Tags: https, secure

I am wondering how magento determines which page should be secure & which page should be unsecure.

From what i understand, magento only makes the checkout & login page as secure by default & i can make other pages secure by specifying them under the config path `frontend/secure_url/....` via my module's config.xml

The admin-side configuration seems to be fine. SSL is enabled in both frontend & backend. The backend is fully over https. In the frontend most pages work fine under http including the homepage, & the checkout & login pages are redirected to https as expected.

But there are a few other url's getting redirected to https that i was expecting to remain on http including a custom module's controller/action.

I need some pointers on how to debug this? Is there any other config i can use to stop them from being redirected?

Comment: Could you give some examples/code (e.g. the custom module's XML config)? Also, I would not speak of "debugging" when you try to redirect https:// to http:// ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is a function just for that, called `shouldUrlBeSecure` located in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` on line `1477`.

Here is the complete function:

```
/**
 * Check whether given path should be secure according to configuration security requirements for URL
 * "Secure" should not be confused with https protocol, it is about web/secure/*_url settings usage only
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return bool
 */
public function shouldUrlBeSecure($url)
{
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_IN_FRONTEND)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!isset($this->_secureUrlCache[$url])) {
        $this->_secureUrlCache[$url] = false;
        $secureUrls = $this->getNode('frontend/secure_url');
        foreach ($secureUrls->children() as $match) {
            if (strpos($url, (string)$match) === 0) {
                $this->_secureUrlCache[$url] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_secureUrlCache[$url];
}
```

To see which URLs should be secure you can add a simple `Mage::log($secureUrls)` inside the `if` statement. This is what my log entry looked like:

```
2014-02-12T11:55:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
(
    [install] => /install/wizard/checkSecureHost
    [customer] => /customer/
    [sales] => /sales/
    [authorizenet_paygate] => /paygate/authorizenet_payment
    [checkout_onepage] => /checkout/onepage
    [checkout_multishipping] => /checkout/multishipping
    [paypal_express] => /paypal/express
    [paypal_standard] => /paypal/standard
    [paypal_express_callbackshippingoptions] => paypal/express/callbackshippingoptions
    [googlecheckout_redirect] => /googlecheckout/redirect/
    [googlecheckout_beacon] => /googlecheckout/api/beacon/
    [googlecheckout_api] => /googlecheckout/api/
    [review_customer] => /review/customer/
    [tag_customer] => /tag/customer/
    [wishlist] => /wishlist/
    [paypaluk_express] => /paypaluk/express
    [rss_catalog_review] => /rss/catalog/review
    [rss_order_new] => /rss/order/new
    [rss_catalog_notifystock] => /rss/catalog/notifystock
    [centinel] => /centinel/
    [newsletter_manage] => /newsletter/manage/
    [downloadable] => /downloadable/customer/
    [downloadable_download] => /downloadable/download/
    [ogone_api] => /ogone/api
    [persistent_onepage_register] => /persistent/index/saveMethod
    [checkout_cart] => /checkout/cart
    [storecredit_info] => /storecredit/info/
    [giftcard_customer] => /giftcard/customer/
    [enterprise_pbridge_pbridge] => /enterprise_pbridge/pbridge/
    [invitation] => /invitation/
)
```

Now to figure out how Magento switches `HTTP` to `HTTPS` *I think* you would most likely have dive into the Zend framework in the `lib` inside `lib/Zend/Http/*` because it contains files of most interest. Well, anyway hope this helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If,you want to used for `secure url`  for `any other modules` then you need to some change in
`config.xml` of that modules.. 
First for frontend used tags

```
<secure_url>
            <productfaq>/productfaq</productfaq>
        </secure_url>
```

And ,if you for productfaq url then change
`$this->getUrl('productfaq/index/index', array('_secure'=>true))`;

My extension path  `\app\code\local\Amit\Productfaq\etc.`

In config.xml need to change below

```
     <frontend>
            <routers>
                <productfaq>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Amit_Productfaq</module>
                        <frontName>onestepcheckout</frontName>
                    </args>
                </productfaq>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <productfaq>
                        <file>productfaq.xml</file>
                    </productfaq>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        <!-- add secure url for extesnion, for that  
url productfaq automatically appnend https:  -->
             <secure_url>
                <productfaq>/productfaq</productfaq>
            </secure_url>
        </frontend>
```